# Regex for a String that starts with 'x' but not 'x98'

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for a string that -

1. Begins with 'x'.
2. After 'x', it does not have '98'

I wrote the following regex, but it isnt working

```
^x[0-8]|^x9[0-7]|^x99.*$
```

Can someone point out what is wrong in it? Or what can be a better regex for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
^x(?!98)\d{2}.*$
```

which will match a string that

- `^x` – starts with `x`
- `\d{2}` – which is followed by two digits (I guessed this from your regex; your description doesn't mention this)
- `(?!98)` – that are *not* 98
- `.*$` – and extends arbitrarily until the end of the string

(I'm not sure what the last requirement is for; I'd probably just go with `^x(?!98)\d{2}`.)

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot! Just wondering what was wrong in what I wrote.

Comment: This depends a bit on how you're matching. Some regex engines have a method that tries performing an *exact* match (e.g. Java's `Matcher.matches()` method), i.e. the string has to match completely. In that case you're in trouble because you match either the strings `x0`, `x1`, ..., `x8`, `x90`, ..., `x97` and `x99...`. Only the last one would include any more characters afterwards. Otherwise (i.e. with a method that matches substrings) it should have worked. That being said, I guess the negative lookahead is easier to understand than modelling ranges.

Answer (score 3):

Should be kind of:

```
^x(?!98).* //(?!pattern) is a negative lookahead
```

Answer (score 1):

this may work for your situation:

```
^x(?!98)
```